# Python VS2013 's Intellisense is not working, "Refresh DB" button is not enabled

Tags: python, visual-studio, intellisense

The  Refresh DB button in Python Environments is not enabled, I can't click on it,  what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Click the warning message, that should fix it